# MySQL single query: find all connections that were active during a minute for every minute for an entire day

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by, pivot

Say I have a table full of each connection that accesses my website, including the following information:

- connection_id (int)
- start_datetime (datetime)
- end_datetime (datetime)
- device_type (int, identifier for accessing through mobile (1), pc (2), other (3), etc.)

I would like to - in a single query - get a count for each minute of a day of all connections that started before or during that minute AND ended during or after that minute. So anyone that were active at any time during that minute. I want to look 6 hours back for start times so I don't check the entire table. For a single minute (2020-01-25 10:10:00), the query would be:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN device_type=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Mobile, 
SUM(CASE WHEN device_type=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS PC, 
SUM(CASE WHEN device_type=3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Other FROM 
connection_table WHERE start_datetime BETWEEN '2020-01-25 04:10:00' AND '2020-01-25 10:10:59' 
AND end_datetime > '2020-01-25 10:10:00';
```

The single query works fine, so I could go through each minute of the day and do this query, but it would be great if I could do this in a single query instead. The single query would of course also need to return a column with the minute it received a count for. I have a table called **all_minutes** with an entry for each minute of the next few years, because I read somewhere that it was a workaround for wanting to get a returned value for each minute *even if I don't necessarily have entries matching that minute in the table*. This table can be joined in, if that helps any.

Is there a way to do this in a single query, though? An example of a preferred returned value set is:

```
Datetime            | Mobile | PC  | Other
2020-01-25 00:00:00 | 30     | 120 | 17
2020-01-25 00:01:00 | 33     | 121 | 18
2020-01-25 00:02:00 | 38     | 122 | 18
2020-01-25 00:03:00 | 37     | 116 | 19
...
2020-01-25 23:59:00 | 30     | 120 | 17
```

I have tried with a subquery, but I haven't made it work. This was one of my attempts, but it loses the ability to use its index when I try to pass all_minutes.the_datetime as "DT" parameter to it. Also I cannot return 3 values in the subquery and doing 3 separate subqueries is not a good option.

```
SELECT the_datetime as dt, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM connection_table WHERE 
start_datetime BETWEEN DATE_SUB(dt, INTERVAL 6 HOUR) 
AND DATE_ADD(dt, INTERVAL 59 SECOND) AND end_datetime > dt) AS connections
FROM all_minutes WHERE the_datetime BETWEEN '2020-01-25 00:00:00' and '2020-01-25 23:59:59';
```

UPDATE: I have also tried by joining the all_minutes table and the connection_table like @spencer7593 and @GMB suggests, but that stops my connection table index (`start_datetime > end_datetime`) from being applied, making it check every single row in the table (and it's a very big table). FORCE INDEX does not work either.

Comment: You have your all minutes, so join it on all_minutes.the_datetime between start time and end time, then group and count the results

Answer (score 0):

the condition for a match ...

```
 WHERE t.start_datetime  >=  '2020-01-25 04:10:00'
   AND t.start_datetime   <  '2020-01-25 10:11:00' 
   AND t.end_datetime     >  '2020-01-25 10:10:00'
```

can we derive those literals from a single value ? consider:

```
 SELECT '2020-01-25 10:10:00'  + INTERVAL -6 HOUR
      , '2020-01-25 10:10:00'  + INTERVAL 1 MINUTE
      , '2020-01-25 10:10:00'  + INTERVAL 0 MINUTE
```

so we know this is equivalent

```
 WHERE t.start_datetime  >=  '2020-01-25 10:10:00'  + INTERVAL -6 HOUR
   AND t.start_datetime   <  '2020-01-25 10:10:00'  + INTERVAL 1 MINUTE 
   AND t.end_datetime     >  '2020-01-25 10:10:00'  + INTERVAL 0 MINUTE
```

now we can replace that literal '2020-01-25 10:10' with an expression

we could do something like this:

```
SELECT m.dt

     , SUM(CASE WHEN t.device_type=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Mobile
     , SUM(CASE WHEN t.device_type=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS PC
     , SUM(CASE WHEN t.device_type=3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Other 

  FROM all_minutes m

  LEFT
  JOIN connection_table t
    ON t.start_datetime  >=  m.dt  + INTERVAL -6 HOUR
   AND t.start_datetime   <  m.dt  + INTERVAL 1 MINUTE 
   AND t.end_datetime     >  m.dt  + INTERVAL 0 MINUTE

 WHERE m.dt >= '2020-01-25 10:00' 
   AND m.dt  < '2020-01-25 10:16'  

 GROUP 
    BY m.dt
```

Comment: This is definitely the kind of thing I'm looking for, however the index on my connection_table is not used with this query so it checks every single row, which will take ages.